# Get cursor position in a sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have two components:

```
class App extends Component {

  insertToStory = (word) => {
    // how to get the cursor position here?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StoryTextarea text={this.props.text} />
        <Toolbar insert={this.insertToStory} />
      </div>
    )
  )

}
```

the `StoryTextarea` contains a textarea, and `Toolbar` contains a button, when clicked, we should insert some word to the textarea under the currrent cursor position. but how can I get the cursor position in `insertToStory`? or is there other ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using refs is a good option to achieve that.

1º Add a new method in your StoryTextArea component to get the cursor position.

```
class StoryTextArea extends React.Component{
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getCursorPosition = this.getCursorPosition.bind(this);
        }
      getCursorPosition(){
          return this.refs.textarea.selectionStart;
      }
      render(){
         return <div>
               <textarea ref="textarea"/>
            </div>
      }
}
```

2º Add a ref to the StoryTextArea component

```
<StoryTextarea ref="storyTextArea" text={this.props.text} />
```

3º Call `getCursorPosition` using `this.refs.storyTextArea.getCursorPosition()`

```
insertToStory = (word) => {
    let position = this.refs.storyTextArea.getCursorPosition();
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/757/)